# Отступы блока фронтенд

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

возникла проблема. Дело в том, что расширяя или уменьшая ширину страницы блок отступает неправильно с одной стороны.

```css
@import "http://fonts.fontstorage.com/import/intro.css";
.header,
.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  color: #8eca98;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 4px solid #f8f2f2;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.timer-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 7px solid #f8f2f2;
}

.content {
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="index-575.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="index-187.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">POMODORO TIMER</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="timer-block">
        <div class="text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, как вы задаете ширину блока с классом `timer-block`. Изначально размеры блока отталкиваются от контента, который находится внутри него. Рамка блока `border` - этим контентом не является.

Т.к вы не указываете поведение блока `box-sizing`, то по-умолчанию оно будет `content-box`, вам же нужен `border-box`, чтобы учитывались границы и любые внутренние отступы.

Изучите по-подробнее блоковую(боксовую) модель CSS. О свойстве `box-sizing` можно прочитать [в топике на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). Там есть интерактивый пример, где можно почувствовать разницу между `content-box` и `border-box`.

В вашем случае стили должны выглядеть так:

```css
.timer-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 7px solid #f8f2f2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, всё работает!